# Docker performance issue with nested Ubuntu KVM

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kvm-virtualization

I have an issue with docker performance in a nested Ubuntu VM. Here's the setup:

> OpenStack Infrastructure
>
> > My Workstation (A)
> >
> > > My Project Host (B)
> > >
> > > > My Project VM (C)

Version info:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04
- Libvirt/KVM: 6.0.0
- docker-ce: 5:24.0.7-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy

I am running a kayobe command that deploys the docker image bifrost-deploy:2023.1-ubuntu-jammy, it's pretty opaque, it uses the docker ansible module.

When I do that on my workstation (A) it takes about 4-5 minutes. When I do that on the project host (B) it takes about 6-7 minutes. That's fine, expected due to the additional layer of virtualization. But when I run that on the project VM (C) it takes 89+ minutes.

I've been trying to troubleshoot this for a while, and I'm not noticing severe performance issues with (C) in general.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

UPDATE:
I disabled THP and that took the build process on (C) down from 89 minutes to 56 minutes, great improvment but it's still taking a really long time..

Comment: Your VM (C) is not an hardware accelerated VM.

Comment: How can I verify or change that? What's interesting is that when I create (C) directly on (A) using the kayobe command then performance is hugely improved, the docker command takes 7-8 minutes.

Comment: Your "OpenStack Infrastructure" needs to support (which it does), your "Workstation (A)" has to support it (which it does), your "Project Host (B)" has to support it, but it doesn't. It's a feature which needs to be activated in your hypervisor at your "Workstation (A)". Consult the documentation of your hypervisor.